# Wavesurfer-js with Typescript waves hidden

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, wavesurfer.js

I am using [wavesurferjs](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) with Angular version 8, so when I use this url [this](http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3) and loaded into wavesurferjs with this configuration

```js
generateWaveform(): void {
    // Write TypeScript code!
    const DEFAULT_AUDIO_HEIGHT: number = 300;
    const DEFAULT_MEDIA_TYPE: string = "audio";

    let userObj = this.app_ser.getCurrentUser()
    console.log('token =', userObj.token);
    Promise.resolve(null).then(() => {
      this.wave = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#waveform',
        waveColor: '#D2EDD4',
        progressColor: '#46B54D',
        skipLength: 2,
        audioRate: 1,
        height: DEFAULT_AUDIO_HEIGHT,
        cursorColor: "#2196F3",
        partialRender: true,
        hideScrollbar: true,
        plugins: [
          TimelinePlugin.create({
            container: '#wave-timeline',
            notchPercentHeight: 70,
            secondaryColor: "#BDBDBD",
            primaryColor: "#c5c5c5",
            secondaryFontColor: "#BDBDBD",
            primaryFontColor: "#c5c5c5"
          }),
          Regions.create({
            regions: [
              {
                start: 1,
                end: 3,
                loop: false,
                color: 'hsla(400, 100%, 30%, 0.5)'
              }, {
                start: 5,
                end: 7,
                loop: false,
                color: 'hsla(200, 50%, 70%, 0.4)'
              }
            ],
            dragSelection: {
              slop: 5
            }
          })
        ],
        drawingContextAttributes: {
          desynchronized: false
        }
      });

      this.wave.on('ready', () => {
        this.wave.play();
      });

     this.wave.on("error", function(error){
        console.log("error = ", error);
      });


onPreviewPressed(url: string): void {
    if (!this.wave) {
      this.generateWaveform();
    }

    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    
    Promise.resolve().then(() => 
// this.wave.load('http://localhost/test/media_files/tes.mp3')
this.wave.load('http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3'));
  }
```

it's working fine without any error, but when I am using my own server that has file and URL look like `http://localhost/test/media_files/tes.mp3`

it's telling me cors origin problem so I added the required configuration to avoid this problem like that

```js
     ...//
     xhr: {
          "cache":"default",
          "mode":"no-cors",
          "method":"GET",
          "credentials":"same-origin",
          "redirect":"follow",
          "referrer":"client",
       }
      ...//
```

the cross origin is solved but another error comes on the console

```js
Error: HTTP error status: 0
    at wavesurfer.js:2803
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39699)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at zone-evergreen.js:855
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
```

and the wavesurfer is not playing.

so while I am reading on documentation of the libarary I notice to add this element

```js
     this.wave = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#waveform',
        waveColor: '#D2EDD4',
        progressColor: '#46B54D',
        backend: 'MediaElement', // this element
```

so wavesurfer player worked but waves are not showing and the same error on console has not gone

```js
Error: HTTP error status: 0
    at wavesurfer.js:2803
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39699)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at zone-evergreen.js:855
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
```

so what is wrong with me? any help please

Comment: So the problem is you cannot load songs from your own server? This may be caused because you use different ports on localhost, causing a CORS (cross-domain) error. You could fix this by allowing cross-domain access on the server where the songs are hosted. The angular code can remain the same.

Comment: is worked but I don't know why has not worked before [they are on the same server frontend and backend].

Comment: Sometimes if you use a different port (for example `localhost:3000` for frontend and `localhost:8000`) for backend, it's still treated as a different domain!

Comment: so I add this code to my server 
```
# Add Audio Types
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/mp3 .mp3

<FilesMatch ".(mp3|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|svg|svgz)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```
on Codeigniter framework but I wonder this will not be a security issue?

Comment: This means that anyone from any server can download or play those audio files, even from javascript. If you don't want that, you can also specify your own allowed domain, instead of using `*`. (The `*` means all domains are allowed, you can change it to `www.mysite.com` to allow only that site).